# What does PEM stand for?

Tags: amazon-ec2, private-key, pem

This might sound like a silly question, but someone asked me what `PEM` stood for, and I just didn't know. I've been using `ec2` for a decent while now, and tried googling for it to no avail (lots of results, but none of them conclusively linked back to the `ec2` files).

Does anyone happen to know? Maybe also some explanation as to why that naming makes sense? My understanding is that the `pem` file basically just serves as a private key, but I'm starting to feel that's not quite the case.

Comment: This is easily Googlable.

Comment: You spent unnecessary time in composing this question on SO. You could have found the answer with way too less efforts had you Googled it. -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stands for **Privacy Enhanced Mail**, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions).

Comment: Privacy-enhanced Electronic Mail